# Google Play Store in-app billing using different google account

Tags: android, google-play-services, in-app-billing, google-play-developer-api, in-app-subscription

I am an amateur developer and having problems trying to implement in-app billing in my android app.

My app has two login functionalities, create an account in the app or login through Facebook.

I am encountering a few problems in this scenario.

Scenario - with server-side storage of account subscription

1. User purchased subscription A in account A using Google Account X.
2. Purchase successful in google play and call API to backend to register subscription to user.
3. API call to server failed. (May have failed either client/server side, for whatever reason)
4. I then store the Purchase token, gmail address, etc. in cache for future API calls and retry after a while.
5. User clears cache of app and logs out Google Account X and logs in Google Account Y. (For whatever reason)
6. User relog-in account A and upon checking BillingClient.queryPurchases() returns empty and no record whatsoever that the user did a purchase at all since it is querying Google Account Y's purchases.

What if user forgot that he used Google Account X for the purchase and then complains that he paid for a subscription that he never received?
Can we handle the scenario above programmatically or should they just email me for support?

Any help is appreciated,

Comment: It is impossible that with a google account you can see purchases from other accounts, it would be a huge security problem if that could be done. Have you thought will happen if? :
The user cancels the subscription or decides not to renew it, even before the end of the grace period with a refund, how will you know if the subscription is active if you cannot call `queryPurchases ()`

Comment: I don't think that is a problem if the API call with purchaseToken was successfully sent from mobile to backend. The backend server will have a continuous job that calls "https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/purchases/subscriptions/get" using the purchaseToken sent to check if the subscription is still valid. So in the scenario I mentioned, what is your take on it? The subscription is essentially "lost" if the user forgets? Unless we store his gmail address before starting a purchase in-app, so we can assist in this scenario in the future? Thanks for the comment also.